# How can I add 100 random elements to an empty array with duplicates?

Tags: java, arrays, random, element

In this code, I'm shuffling 100 random elements instead of adding 100 random elements with duplicates, and returning 10 unique keys. How can I do that?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> uniqueKeys = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        uniqueKeys.add(new Integer(i));
    }
    Collections.shuffle(uniqueKeys);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(uniqueKeys.get(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be using `Random` to generate your elements.

Comment: Look at your for loop - you have 101 iterations instead of 100. Use i<100 or i=1; i<101 or i=1; i<=100 etc.

Comment: if you are allowing *duplicates* why is the reference named `uniqueKeys`?

Comment: Is this for your homework? Use `Random` to generate the unique ints, then use `HashMap`... Anyway, it's probably better if you would do your own research and try some experiments with your code. Try researching the classes that I've mentioned.

Comment: yeah this was for homework. Jarrod, I just asked how to add random integers with duplicates because I planned to change ArrayList to TreeSet myself and filter out the duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a combination of Set and Random. Using Set, you will get rid of duplicates. Using Random, you will get (pseudo) random numbers.

```
final int KEYS_COUNT = 100;
final int MAX_KEY_VALUE = 1000;

Set<Integer> setOfKeys = new HashSet<>();
Random random = new Random();

while (setOfKeys.size() <= KEYS_COUNT) {
    setOfKeys.add(random.nextInt(MAX_KEY_VALUE));
}
```

The Set `setOfKeys` will contain 100 unique random numbers with their values less then 1000. You can then use [toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#toArray(T[])) method to make array from the Set.

If you make `KEYS_COUNT` equal to `MAX_KEY_VALUE`, the values won't be much random, they will be only shuffled.